# Add filters to query dynamically using pyscopg2

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

Trying to creating a dynamic filter, i'm having a difficulty for printing  where statement without "quotation marks".

Output: `select "col1", "col2" from "table1" where "col2=1234" and "col3=column1"`

Desired: `select "col1", "col2" from "table1" where col2="1234" and col3="column1"`

```
def filter(table,*args,**kwarg):
 query = sql.SQL("select {0} from {1} where {2}").format(
    sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier,[arg for arg in args])),
    sql.Identifier(table),
    sql.SQL(' and ').join(map(sql.Identifier,{(str(k)+'='+str(v)) for k,v in kwarg.iteritems()}))
    )
 print query.as_string(Connection())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encoding each condition as a single SQL identifier - i.e., you are essentially encoding `sql.Identifier('foo=bar')`

Another pitfall is that you are putting the query values directly in the SQL; though you may trust the source,
generally speaking that will be a bad idea. Better is to use a placeholder, and provide the actual values 
at execution time.

Finally - list comprehensions are generally preferred over `map`; that is a style choice, though.

Putting those together, the predicate will render correctly with something like this:

```
def filter(table, *args, **kwargs):
  conditions = [sql.SQL(' = ').join([sql.Identifier(k), sql.Placeholder()]) for k in kwarg.keys()]
  query = sql.SQL("select {0} from {1} where {2}").format(
     sql.SQL(', ').join([sql.Identifier(arg) for arg in args]),
     sql.Identifier(table),
     sql.SQL(' and ').join(conditions)
  )
```

This does assume that the underlying dict is not modified between query construction and execution. Your "execute" would be something like:

```
cursor.execute(sql, kwargs.values())
```

If that assumption does not hold, replace `sql.Placeholder()` with `sql.Literal(v)` in the `conditions` comprehension, and use `kwargs.items()` instead of `kwargs.keys()`. In that case, I *think* that `Literal` will correctly escape just about any risky string, but safer to use placeholders and parameters.

Hope that helps